# Replace string with new value

Tags: excel, vba

My Sheet Name is Eg: `PMCC 1` and I have Content in sheet is `PMCC#01`.
I would like to Convert Sheet Name into `PMCC#01` with replace function.

I tried this code

```
temp = ws.Name
newtemp = Replace(temp,"","#0")
```

As result, I only get 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't you just need:

```
ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, " ", "#0")
```

Main difference is `" "` instead of `""`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook

        For Each ws In .Worksheets '<- Loop all sheets
            With ws
                strName = .Range("A1") '<- Let us assume that the new name appears in all sheets at range A1
                .Name = strName '<- Change sheet name
            End With
        Next ws

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is: you have created a variable, you have entered a value in it, coming from the sheet name, and you believe that modifying the value of that variable will automatically modify your sheet name.

This is not the way variables work: you specifically need to put your variable's value into the sheet name, something like:

```
temp = ws.Name
newtemp = Replacement_function(temp, ...) // not sure to use `Replace()` or `Substitute()`
ws.Name = newtemp
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the numeric element of your worksheet name can be 10 or higher, you might want to do this:

```
temp = Split(ws_Name, " ")
newtemp = temp(0) & "#" & Format(temp(1), "00")
```

That way, `PMCC 1` becomes `PMCC#01` but `PMCC 13` would become `PMCC#13`, not `PMCC#013`